# SvelteKit `dist/index.d.ts` exports component instead of types

Tags: typescript, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit (v1.5) vite library project that exports a single component from `dist/index.js`:

```
export { default as Settings } from './components/Settings.svelte';
```

I also have one simple type definition in `src/types/index.d.ts` I would like to export for lib users:

```js
//...
export type SettingsWritable = ...
```

I - maybe naively - would expect this to be exported by `dist/index.d.ts`. However `dist/index.d.ts` has the same content as `dist/index.js` - exporting the component as above.

Is my expectation wrong? If not, how would I make sure my type definitions (currently in  `src/types/index.d.ts`) are exported correctly?

Here are some possibly helpful `package.json` properties:

```json
"exports": {
    ".": {
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
        "svelte": "./dist/index.js"
    }
},
"files": [
    "dist",
    "!dist/**/*.test.*",
    "!dist/**/*.spec.*",
    "build",
    "riga-tool.config.json"
],
"main": "./dist/index.js",
"svelte": "./dist/index.js",
"types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
"type": "module"
```

I'm also using the standard tsconfig from the SvelteKit starter repo:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // ...
        "rootDirs": [
            "..",
            "./types"
        ],
        // ...
    },
    "include": [
        "ambient.d.ts",
        "./types/**/$types.d.ts",
        "../vite.config.ts",
        "../src/**/*.js",
        "../src/**/*.ts",
        "../src/**/*.svelte",
        "../tests/**/*.js",
        "../tests/**/*.ts",
        "../tests/**/*.svelte"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "../node_modules/**",
        "./[!ambient.d.ts]**",
        "../src/service-worker.js",
        "../src/service-worker.ts",
        "../src/service-worker.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Many thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Do you use TS in the source? Then you should be able to export any types you need alongside the components. Not sure how one would export types from raw JS.

Comment: Yes - the source is TS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types for components are generated automatically and should be provided as `[name].svelte.d.ts`, if you need to expose additional types, you can just export them alongside the components. E.g.

```js
export { default as Settings } from './components/Settings.svelte';
export * from './types'; // if there is an index.ts
```

Would recommend using `.ts` for "new" types and `.d.ts` only if the type declarations are for existing `.js`/other files.